# How would I write a query to give me the following results?

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

I have 2 classes.

Activities and Comments.

Activities, is linked to comments.

Comments, has the fields username, comment and created_at

---

When I execute `select from Activities`, this is an example of my current results. Below, you will see an example of my desired results (Example 2)

Example 1

```
{
            "@type": "d",
            "@rid": "#28:38",
            "@version": 10,
            "@class": "Activities",
            "activity_type_id": 1,
            "username": "johnt",
            "title": "random new activitie test",
            "image": "http://www.someurl.com/images/blah-2.png",
            "comments": [
                "#24:26",
                "#24:27",
                "#24:28",
                "#24:29",
                "#24:30",
                "#24:31"
            ],
            "Activity_Properties": {
                "comment_count": 0,
                "share_count": 0,
                "like_count": 0
            }
        }
```

**my desired results are the following**

Example 2

```
{
    "@type": "d",
    "@rid": "#28:38",
    "@version": 10,
    "@class": "Activities",
    "activity_type_id": 1,
    "username": "ultimaterandomuser",
    "title": "random new activitie test",
    "image": "http://www.someurl.com/images/blah.png",
    "comments": [
           {
          "username": "randomuser1",
          "comment": "randomuser1 comment"
          "created_at": "2016-06-23 00:00:00",
       },
           {
          "username": "randomuser2",
          "comment": "randomuser2 comment"
          "created_at": "2016-06-23 00:00:00",
       },
           {
          "username": "randomuser3",
          "comment": "randomuser3 comment"
          "created_at": "2016-06-23 00:00:00",
       }
 ],
    "Activity_Properties": {
        "comment_count": 0,
        "share_count": 0,
        "like_count": 0,
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @JTD, do you have a simple DB test ? Or a script to reproduce your dataset with correct properties types and values ?

Comment: Hi @JTD, I've just answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your case with this simple dataset:

[image]

**Output Query 1:**

```
SELECT FROM Activities

{
    "result": [
        {
            "@type": "d",
            "@rid": "#12:0",
            "@version": 1,
            "@class": "Activities",
            "activity_type_id": 1,
            "username": "ultimaterandomuser",
            "title": "random new activitie test",
            "image": "http://www.someurl.com/images/blah.png",
            "comments": [
                "#13:0",
                "#13:1",
                "#13:2"
            ],
            "Activity_Properties": {
                "comment_count": 0,
                "share_count": 0,
                "like_count": 0
            },
            "@fieldTypes": "comments=n"
        }
    ],
    "notification": "Query executed in 0.01 sec. Returned 1 record(s)"
}
```

**Output Query 2:**

```
SELECT expand(@this.exclude('comments')) FROM (SELECT *, $comments as commentsList FROM Activities
    LET $comments = (SELECT expand(@this.exclude('@rid')) FROM (SELECT username, comment, created_at FROM Comments WHERE @rid IN $parent.current.comments)))

{
    "result": [
        {
            "@type": "d",
            "@rid": "#12:0",
            "@version": 1,
            "@class": "Activities",
            "activity_type_id": 1,
            "username": "ultimaterandomuser",
            "title": "random new activitie test",
            "image": "http://www.someurl.com/images/blah.png",
            "Activity_Properties": {
                "comment_count": 0,
                "share_count": 0,
                "like_count": 0
            },
            "commentsList": [
                {
                    "@type": "d",
                    "@version": 0,
                    "username": "randomuser1",
                    "comment": "randomuser1 comment",
                    "created_at": "2016-06-25 03:33:13",
                    "@fieldTypes": "created_at=t"
                },
                {
                    "@type": "d",
                    "@version": 0,
                    "username": "randomuser2",
                    "comment": "randomuser2 comment",
                    "created_at": "2016-06-25 03:33:13",
                    "@fieldTypes": "created_at=t"
                },
                {
                    "@type": "d",
                    "@version": 0,
                    "username": "randomuser3",
                    "comment": "randomuser3 comment",
                    "created_at": "2016-06-25 03:33:13",
                    "@fieldTypes": "created_at=t"
                }
            ],
            "@fieldTypes": "commentsList=z"
        }
    ],
    "notification": "Query executed in 0.041 sec. Returned 1 record(s)"
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi @JTD, is my answer correct ? Does it work correctly in your case ?

Comment: Hi @JTD, if you believe that this is the correct answer, could you mark it as such ?

Comment: yes, it is correct. my apologies for not marking it as correct